# How do I disable a CSS line that is causing a bug in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

My users with IE7 were reporting that borders were missing for the second column in tables.  I was finally able to track down what's causing it--a single line in telerik.common.css which is included because various pages on the site use Telerik's MVC extensions.

I would like to be able to disable just that one line for just IE7 (no bug in IE6 or later IE versions). The example below uses text color instead of borders.

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
table.Standard td
{
    color: black;
}
table.Standard tr.First td
{
    color: red;
}

/* Line that makes all cells in the second column red */
.t-grid .t-group-cell+td,.t-grid .t-hierarchy-cell+td{border-left-width: 0}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="Standard" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" border="0">
    <tr class="First">
        <td class="First">red</td>
        <td>red</td>
        <td>red</td>
        <td>red</td>
        <td>red</td>
        <td>red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="First">black</td>
        <td>black</td>
        <td>black</td>
        <td>black</td>
        <td>black</td>
        <td>black</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="First">black</td>
        <td>black</td>
        <td>black</td>
        <td>black</td>
        <td>black</td>
        <td>black</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Expected output:

[image: expected output]

#### IE7 output:

[image: IE7 output]

### [Live example](http://tgmayfield.com/sandbox/ie7-adjacency.html)

### Tests with online browser previews

#### Browserling

[browserling http://tgmayfield.com/sandbox/ie7-adjacency/Browserling-thumbnail.png](http://tgmayfield.com/sandbox/ie7-adjacency/Browserling.png)

#### Adobe Browserlab

[Browserlab http://tgmayfield.com/sandbox/ie7-adjacency/Browserlab-thumbnail.png](http://tgmayfield.com/sandbox/ie7-adjacency/Browserlab.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/brKjT There must be something else going on. Are you sure it's this rule that's causing the problem?

Comment: You could try to do a conditional comment for IE7 that overwrite the styles for that line of code.  Unfortunately, while your example explains the problem, it's not actually causing a problem in IE7 so there's nothing to troubleshoot.  You'd have to post your actual code, which sounds like it might be pretty extensive.  Line numbers could help in this case. http://jsfiddle.net/HRPgr/

Comment: The screenshots above are taken with the exact code displayed.

Comment: Without jsfiddle: http://tgmayfield.com/sandbox/ie7-adjacency.html

Comment: Even with your live example, I'm not seeing the indicated output in IE7 (on Win 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to verify the bug using a real installation of IE7. For whatever reason, the bug doesn't appear using IE9's browser mode for IE7.

I was able to filter out the offending CSS by using this nasty looking hack: `head ~ /* */ body`

So anything after the body declaration in that hack will be understood by all browsers except IE7

```
head ~ /* */ body .t-grid .t-group-cell+td, head ~ /* */ body .t-grid .t-hierarchy-cell+td{border-left-width: 0}
```

Comment: It's rare for a bug to be in IE7 but not IE9's IE7 mode. I deleted my answer after checking the test case in the question in IE7. :/ http://i.stack.imgur.com/BrbJO.png